# Methods of max() and sum() undefined in the Java Spark Dataframe API (1.4.1)

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

Putting sample code of `DataFrame.groupBy()` into my code, but it shown the methods of `max()` and `sum()` undefined.

```
df.groupBy("department").agg(max("age"), sum("expense"));
```

Which Java package should I import if I want to use `max()` and `sum()` method?

Is the Syntax correct of this sample code?

Comment: import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*; make it works

Answer (score 11):

The import didn't work for me. Eclipse IDE still showed the compilation error.

But the following method call worked

```
df.groupBy("Gender").agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max(df.col("Id")), org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum(df.col("Income")));
```

In case the aggregation involves only one field, we can also use the following syntax,

```
df.groupBy("Gender").max("Income");
```

Comment: Put "import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;" for eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 7):

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*
```

Try this to import all functions including `max` and `sum`

Answer (score 3):

Try `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

**EDIT.**

From what I've noticed you are using scala syntax, trying to acces columns via apply method. For Java, you have to pass columns like with `.col` method this:

```
df.groupBy("department").agg(max(df.col("age")), sum(df.col("expense")));
```

See Java example  [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

Comment: Thanks, but Java (1.7) does not support "_" and there not  "org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*" in API.

Comment: Answer fixed. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're searching for "org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData"

To use them in your code like you've written it, you'll need a static import.

[Link to Api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData)

Always try to have a look at the API descriptions first.